# how to serialize object to concrete object

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-web-api2

I have a method:

```
public object getData()
{
   //make an external call
}
```

when executing `getData()`, we get an object that looks like this:

```
{  
   "Location": 
      {  
         "LocationID":1,
         "ABCIsCopperFiberNidBit":0,
         "ABCCopperJunctionID":0,
         "ABCFiberJunctionID":0,
         "ABCGrade":0,
         "ABCCopperDSLAMDistance":0
      }
}
```

from the above i need to convert this to a concrete datatype

such as a `List` of these:

```
public class LocationModel
{
   public int locationId{get;set;}
   public string key {get;set;}
   public string value {get;set;}
}
```

the result I am looking for is a `List<LocationModel>`:

```
locationid=1,
key=ABCIsCopperFiberNidBit,
value=0


locationid=1
key = ABCCopperJunctionID,
value=0
```

etc

**How do I convert from this object to the desired strongly-typed datatype?**

My question is not for the purpose of you to do my work for me. I am a moderately-experienced developer, and I am having trouble digging through all the different ways of accomplishing this task.

Comment: That looks like a *string*, not an object. Change the return type to `string` and use JSON.NET to deserialize it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the return datatype is _object_, something i cannot change, so are you suggesting i can simply cast it to a ```string```?

Comment: Your `LocationModel` has nothing to do with the json string though. In fact, it's the *opposite* of strongly-typed. Instead of deserializing the string into a stronly typed object with `Location`, LocationId etc you want to generate an *untyped* list of key/values? Why?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos good question, it's bad design, but it's what we have to work with the client

Comment: I'm saying this is *NOT* an object. *You* should tell us what the type is. Inspect it in the debugger. Add a watch variable and check its type. It looks like a string that contains JSON

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos sorry i am misunderstanding.  i _do_ know that the type is _object_, are you suggesting that at runtime it will determine the exact type, and probably set it to string? this makes sense to me, but i never knew that it works this way

Comment: `we have to work with the client` if you want an answer you'll have to explain what you want and why. Did the client explicitly demand an array of key/value object in the REST response instead of the JSON string? Does *your* code require it?

Comment: No, the type is NOT object. `object` has NO properties and methods except for `GetType()`, `GetString()` and a couple of others. What you posted is a string returned as an object. Nothing else looks like this in .NET

Comment: When you say "we get an object that looks like this" do you mean there's actually a C# object which has that structure, but it's not currently cast as that object type at compile-time, or do you mean you're getting a JSON string that looks like what you posted?

Comment: Anyway, what you ask is how to *flatten* the JSON string. You can use JSON.NET to read the string element by element and extract each element's name and value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like Json.NET would work well:

```
string json = @"{
 ""Location"": 
      {  
         ""LocationID"":1,
         ""ABCIsCopperFiberNidBit"":0,
         ""ABCCopperJunctionID"":0,
         ""ABCFiberJunctionID"":0,
         ""ABCGrade"":0,
         ""ABCCopperDSLAMDistance"":0
      }
}";
```

then:

```
    var obj = (JObject)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
    var loc = obj["Location"];

    var locid = loc["LocationID"].Value<int>();
    var list = new List<LocationModel>();
    foreach(var prop in loc.Children().OfType<JProperty>())
    {
        if (prop.Name == "LocationID") continue;
        list.Add(new LocationModel
        {
            locationId = locid,
            key = prop.Name,
            value = prop.Value.ToString()
        });
    }
```